# Error after creating dashboard with django-admin-tools

Tags: django, django-admin

I have installed django-admin-tools and created dashboard.py (default one). When I run my admin it's giving me a syntax error Exception:

> Caught Warning while rendering: Field 'dashboard_id' doesn't have a
>   default value

Comment: i altered the table admin_tools_dashboard_preferences setting empty string ('') as default value, then it worked